# change background color of gradio's bubble text box

Tags: css, gradio

I have been looking for ways to change background color of gradio's bubble text box by using the `color_map` property. Unfortunately `color_map` has been deprecated.

As a result, the following command has not been successful:

```
gr.Chatbot(elem_id="chat").style(color_map=["blue", "green"])
```

I have also attempted to set `background-color` on `elem_id` via an external CSS, but the outcome has not improved.